# Can't Debug Flutter Project on Android Simulator Because of instagram_basic_display_api

Tags: android, flutter, dart

## Error

When I try Android debugging, the errors displayed.

I'm trying to use [instagram_basic_display_api](https://pub.dev/packages/instagram_basic_display_api) package but it doesn't work.

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\instagram_basic_display_api-1.0.1\android\build.gradle' line: 29
2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':instagram_basic_display_api'.
> D:\FlutterProjects\project1\android\secret.properties (�w�肳�ꂽ�t�@�C����������܂���B)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 471
```

I tried `flutter pub remove instagram_basic_display_api`, `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. But still this error.

And the strange thing is that some of the errors are garbled.

```
> D:\FlutterProjects\project1\android\secret.properties (�w�肳�ꂽ�t�@�C����������܂���B)
```

If I remove `instagram_basic_display_api` from `pubspec.yaml`, build successful.

Also what is this `secret.properties`? I can't see it with exploror.
I didn't change any files in `android` directory before this error occurs.

## flutter doctor -v

I think this is a problem about package, not Flutter own.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739], locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at C:\Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (10 days ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\yukik.000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.11)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.32228.343
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\yukik.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)       • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739]
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 101.0.4951.67
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.41

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

How can I solve this?